# Display Web Front End IP address in SharePoint 2016 Masterpage

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page

is there a way to display the IP address of the web front end on a site's masterpage? I have a table at the bottom of my masterpage where I'd like to store the code. I'm running load-balancing and would like some indication of which server I'm hitting by displaying the WFE IP at the bottom.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet in your masterpage (replace `Console.WriteLine` with assigning text to your control):

```
String strHostName = string.Empty;
strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
{
    if (!addr[i].IsIPv6LinkLocal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IP Address: {0} ", addr[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

Also, I suggest you make the foreground color equal to background color. That way no one will see it and you'll be able to select it with mouse.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803073/get-local-ip-address